# How to advertise a paper to increase citations?

Tags: publications, citations, online-resource, physics, online-publication

Of course, the best way to improve citations is to write good papers which presents sound, interesting, and important results.

However, assuming that one has a nice paper published in an important journal (e.g., PRL, or PRB), what one can do to improve citations, and in general to make people read, or at least aware of, the paper? A partial answer is to upload it on the arXiv, and presents the work to relevant conferences on the topic. Is there something else one can do to *advertise* a paper, especially online?

PS: I am concerned with hard-sciences, in particular, physics.

Comment: I have heard decent things about academia.edu, they claim citations are generally higher when they are used as well but no idea if the claims are valid. I've never used it personally.

Comment: I suspect the best way is to engage in discussions of the topic of your paper on blogs/forums, where it would be perfectly natural to mention your paper.  That also has the advantage of getting the information to the people most likely to cite it (because it will be useful for them).

Comment: @DikranMarsupial Blogs and forums are usually not read by people in academia, to my knowledge. Or maybe are there some more specialistic research-level forums/blogs out there?

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner I have great cynicism about the academia.edu study; see caveats here - http://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/2015/05/18/citation-boost-or-bad-data-academia-edu-research-under-scrutiny/

Comment: "How to advertise a paper to increase citations?". By writing more quality papers that build on this paper and cite it.

Comment: @Alexandros: with the emphasis being on "quality". Don't just self-cite every one of your previous papers that is even only vaguely related.

Comment: In my area (stats/machine learning) there are several blogs/forums where methods are discussed.  I suspect it is the same for many other fields (you could always start one - if you have interesting things to say, there will be an audience - which is why I don't have a blog ;o).  The point is that actively discussing ideas with other scientists is likely to be more effective than passive advertising.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Aside from giving **excellent** talks at **important** conferences, here are several other ideas.  I've seen all of these work (although rarely all for the same paper).

- Maintain a freely available copy (or at least an arXiv link) on your personal web page.
- Keep your CV up to date, including links to freely available version of *all* your papers.
- Make sure Google Scholar and similar indexing services are indexing your paper.
- Announce / brag about your paper on social media: Facebook, Twitter, Google+, LinkedIn, Tumblr, Pinterest, LiveJournal, etc.
- If you have pages at clickbait sites like Academia.org or ResearchGate, upload copies (of the arXiv version) there.  (But if you don't, don't start now.)
- Write a blog post about your paper.  Better yet, convince someone else with a well-read blog to write a blog post about your paper.
- Give invited talks about your work at other universities/labs.  If necessary, invite yourself.
- If you are a student, ask your advisor to brag about your new paper.
- If your paper significantly extends the work of other authors, or applies it in a novel way, contact those authors directly with a link to (a free version of) your paper.  (But don't send a copy to someone just because you cite them.)
- Whenever your paper provides an answer to a question on (for example) physics.stackexchange, answer the question and include a link to your paper.
- Develop a reputation for stellar work, so that people in your field regularly check your web page / arXiv / indexes / journals for your newest papers.

The last method is by far the most effective.

Comment: +1 for "Develop a reputation for stellar work, so that people in your field regularly check your web page...". Similary, I "subscribe" to the Google Scholar profile of people that do great work in my area of interest so that I am notified by Google whenever they publish a new paper.

Comment: I suspect most of these methods have such tiny benefit that they are not worth the effort.  But some are very important.  Which?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist First, develop a reputation for stellar work.  Second, make your work freely and easily available.  Third, talk about your work in public (in whatever way works best for you).

Answer (score 7):

Go to conferences and give talks that describe the results in the paper, giving the citation as part of your slides. In disciplines where conferences are not primary publication venues, there's no real worry about the conference paper duplicating the journal article because there's usually no conference paper at all. There are plenty of big conferences that have no proceedings and talks are accepted by review of abstracts only. I don't know if this is how physics works, but in computational mechanics, it's the norm.

Comment: Yes, present the work to conferences is of course an important way to advertise a paper, as I said in the question. I asked explicitly about other way to do it, e.g., online.

Comment: I think your answer is not an answer to my question